# Vertically centering movieclip on resize

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

My company has a product that can block various content types online, and I'm currently working on the design for when a `*.swf` file is blocked.  It's been years since I've worked in Flash and I need some help. **This must be written in ActionScript 2 to ensure maximum compatibility!**

I have a movie clip with 4 frames, I switch frames to show different logo layouts depending on the stage size/ratio. In all cases though, the logo should be centered on the stage which is where I am having issues.  It's very close to being centered, but it is off by enough that the logo gets cut off in some scenarios.

The code in question is on the first frame.  In general, all I'm doing to center the movie clip is:

```
Stage.align = "TC";
Stage.scaleMode = "noscale";

var blockedContent:MovieClip = _root.mc_blocked;
var stageListener:Object = new Object();
stageListener.onResize = function() {
    blockedContent._y = (Stage.height/2)-(blockedContent._height/2);`
};
Stage.addListener(stageListener);
```

---

But here is the code in its entirety so you can see it in context.

```
// set the Flash movie to have a fixed anchor in the top top center of the screen.
Stage.align = "TC";
// prevent the Flash movie from resizing when the window changes size.
Stage.scaleMode = "noscale";

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//Add a new listener when the stage is resized
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
var stageListener:Object = new Object();
stageListener.onResize = function() {
    fixLayout();
};
Stage.addListener(stageListener);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//Define some variables
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
var blockedContent:MovieClip = _root.mc_blocked;
var StageRatio:Number = 0;
var Sizes:Object = {
    Padding:20,
    VLarge:{w:0, h:0},
    VSmall:{w:0, h:0},
    HLarge:{w:0, h:0},
    HSmall:{w:0, h:0}
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//duplicate the clip, and save the sizes for each frame
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
duplicateMovieClip(blockedContent, "mc_duplicate", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
mc_duplicate._alpha = 0;
mc_duplicate.gotoAndStop(1);
Sizes.VLarge.w = mc_duplicate._width;
Sizes.VLarge.h = mc_duplicate._height;
mc_duplicate.gotoAndStop(2);
Sizes.HLarge.w = mc_duplicate._width;
Sizes.HLarge.h = mc_duplicate._height;
mc_duplicate.gotoAndStop(3);
Sizes.VSmall.w = mc_duplicate._width;
Sizes.VSmall.h = mc_duplicate._height;
mc_duplicate.gotoAndStop(4);
Sizes.HSmall.w = mc_duplicate._width;
Sizes.HSmall.h = mc_duplicate._height;
//Remove it, we are done with it
mc_duplicate.removeMovieClip();

//Uncomment to see if it is centered
//mc_duplicate._alpha = 25;
//mc_duplicate.gotoAndStop(1);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//Fix the layout and scale things appropriately
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
function fixLayout() {

    StageRatio = Stage.width/Stage.height;
    //derermine which way to scale the logo
    if (Stage.height-Sizes.Padding>Sizes.VLarge.h+Sizes.Padding || (StageRatio>0.67 && StageRatio<2.45)) {
        if (Stage.width-Sizes.Padding<Sizes.VSmall.w+Sizes.Padding) {
            //Small vertical layout (no logo)
            blockedContent.gotoAndStop(3);
        } else {
            //default state - the large vertical layout
            blockedContent.gotoAndStop(1);
        }
    } else {
        //if it's not as tall as the large vertical...
        if (Stage.width-Sizes.Padding<Sizes.HSmall.w+Sizes.Padding) {
            //Use the small horizontal (no logo)
            blockedContent.gotoAndStop(4);
        } else {
            //Use the large horizontal
            blockedContent.gotoAndStop(2);
        }
    }
    //make sure it's never larger than 100%
    blockedContent._xscale = blockedContent._yscale=100;

    //Resize by the height...
    if (blockedContent._height+Sizes.Padding>Stage.height-Sizes.Padding) {
        blockedContent._height = Stage.height-Sizes.Padding;
        //Match the scales
        blockedContent._xscale = blockedContent._yscale;
    }
    //Resize by the width...  
    if (blockedContent._width+Sizes.Padding>Stage.width-Sizes.Padding) {
        blockedContent._width = Stage.width-Sizes.Padding;
        //Match the scales
        blockedContent._yscale = blockedContent._xscale;
    }

    //Center it up   
    blockedContent._y = (Stage.height/2)-(blockedContent._height/2); //-Sizes.Padding*2;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//Fade it in, and initially call the layout fix
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
blockedContent._alpha = 0;
setTimeout(function(){
    blockedContent.onEnterFrame=function(){
        this._alpha+=3;
        if(this._alpha>=100){
            delete this.onEnterFrame;
        }
    }
},300);
fixLayout();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content inside of your `blockedContent` MovieClip is centered already. So, all you would have to do is center the MC according to the Stage height (divided by half). Just remove the `(blockedContent._height/2)` portion of your code:

```
blockedContent._y = (Stage.height/2);
```

Comment: Oh geez, I knew it was something easy like that... thanks!  I'll accept the answer when it allows me to.  I had a previous version of this file that must have not been vertically centered inside the clip, so that's where I got confused at.